# Rails Query to get all Posts in Forum Topic and then User for Each Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please bear with a Ruby on Rails noob who is trying to create a first original application.

Here are my associations:

```
class Forum
  has_many :topics
  has_many :posts
end

class Topic
  has_many :topics
  belongs_to :forum
end

class User
  has_many :posts
end

class Post
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic
end
```

I want to make a query for a Topic show page that first gets all Posts in that Topic; they have `topic_id` as a foreign key to tie them to the Topic. I have successfully gotten that far with:

```
@topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
@posts = Post.where("topic_id = ?", @topic.id)
```

I then want to get each User for each of these Posts by using the foreign key user_id that is in each Post’s record. I wondered if somehow I should nest attributes but just cannot figure out the proper Rails  syntax to then get each Post’s User.

The final Topic show view would have something like:

Topic #1
     Post #1 Title
     Post #1 Body
     Posted by User.username at Post.created_at

Post #2 Title
     Post #2 Body
     Posted by User.username at Post.created_at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want a `@users` variable as other answers suggest.  While it's true that mapping to a new array would give you the one-to-one relationship between posts and authors that you're looking for, it would require extra logic in your view to display.

What you're really looking for is for your view to reach into each post and get its `user`, which you already support with your associations.  You can structure your view like this:

```
<h1><%= @topic.name %></h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <h2><%= p.title %></h2>
  <p><%= p.body %></p>
  <p>Posted by <%= p.user.username %> at <%= p.created_at %></p>
<% end %>
```

Since that `p.user.username` is a law of demeter violation, you may want to [delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) to the post user, or write the `to_s` of `User` such that `p.user` returns their username (depending on your usage through the app).

Comment: Sometimes this works, and sometimes it doesn't! In my view I get the `error  undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: That's the Law of Demeter violation I was talking about.  When you write `x.y_method.z_method`, you're assuming that y_method returns _something_ useful.  If instead it returns `nil` (in your care, if a post doesn't have a user), then trying to call `z_method` will fail with that error.  Delegating lets you teach your posts how to be a bit smarter- they can ask their user for the username and, if you use the `allow_nil` option, it can handle the case where there is no user.

Comment: So I added in my posts and comments models `allow_nil: true`, such as `delegate :username, to: :user, allow_nil: true`, and I am still getting "error undefined method username for nil:NilClass." I know that the Law of Demeter is limiting access of different objects to each other, andI thought delegating would work. Is there a way other than `delegate` that might permit me to associate the user_id on each post and comment with a user and show their usenames?

Comment: There are plenty of ways, but `delegate`, as you've written, should do exactly what you're thinking.

Comment: Finally realized that under `@comment.each do |comment|` that the delegated elements should be comment.avatar and comment.username, because they have been delegated! Fixed the errors quite nicely. I also went and read more in depth on `delegate` and Law of Demeter just to get the concepts down.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the *map* function.

```
@users = @posts.map(&:user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
@topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
@posts = @topic.posts 
   //instead of doing
   @posts = Post.where("topic_id = ?", @topic.id)
@post_users = @posts.map(&:user)
```